# Tengo una pregunta con el uso del return

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y yo tenia este codigo de acá, que lo saque de un libro:

```
>>> def cuadrado (x):
... cuadrado = x * x
... return cuadrado
```

pero cuando lo uso en python me dice que x no esta definido. Me pueden ayudar con eso? Me parece que es porque ese libro es de python 2 y yo estoy usando python 3 creo.

Comment: Formatea bien el código de tu pregunta, porque al parecer es un problema de identación

Comment: Tienes que llamar a la función `cuadrado` pasándole un valor como parámetro, por ejemplo: `cuadrado(2)` y te devolverá `4`...

Comment: Pulsá en el enlace que dice "editada hace..." y vas a ver qué agregó Yussef para que tu código se vea como tal. Son triples acentos graves (en inglés: _backticks_, `) una línea antes y una después del código.

Comment: Estaría bien que agregaras la traza completa del error tal como te lo muestra el interprete. ciertamente el código esta mal sangrado, pero el error que mencionas no concuerda con el código que muestras, ese código ejecutado tanto a través de un script como a través del REPL (que es lo que parece que usas) genera un `IndentationError` en la segunda linea y no un `NameError`...

Answer (score 1):

En Python es muy importante la sangría o *indentado*.

El código que indicas se ve bien en cuanto a lógica, pero el problema parece deberse al indentado. Este código debería funcionar:

```
def cuadrado (x):
    cuadrado = x * x
    return cuadrado
```

Es importante es que todas las instrucciones que pertenecen a un mismo bloque tengan la misma cantidad de espacios al inicio. Es la forma que Python tiene para saber a qué bloque corresponde una instrucción.

En otros lenguajes simplemente no importa ya que los bloques están delimitados por llaves, por ejemplo, en C:

```
int cuadrado(int x){
    return x * x;
}
```